# MUI Chips as tags that can be selected (checkbox like behavior)

Tags: reactjs, json, typescript, material-ui

I have a JSON file where I am getting the data of the chips from

```
[
    { "id": "4", "name": "Caucasian" },
    { "id": "5", "name": "Asian" },
    { "id": "6", "name": "Middle Eastern" },
    { "id": "7", "name": "Eurasian" },
    { "id": "8", "name": "African" },
    { "id": "10", "name": "Caribbean" },
    { "id": "11", "name": "Scandinavian European" },
    { "id": "12", "name": "Afro American" },
    { "id": "13", "name": "Latin American" },
    { "id": "14", "name": "European" },
    { "id": "15", "name": "Slavic European" },
    { "id": "16", "name": "American Indian" },
    { "id": "17", "name": "Inuit" },
    { "id": "21", "name": "Aboriginal/Torres Strait" },
    { "id": "22", "name": "Maori" },
    { "id": "23", "name": "Pacific Islander" },
    { "id": "24", "name": "Indian" },
    { "id": "26", "name": "Cambodian" },
    { "id": "27", "name": "Korean" },
    { "id": "28", "name": "Vietnamese" },
    { "id": "29", "name": "Thai" },
    { "id": "30", "name": "Chinese" },
    { "id": "31", "name": "Malaysian" },
    { "id": "32", "name": "Filipino" },
    { "id": "33", "name": "Japanese" },
    { "id": "34", "name": "Indonesian" },
    { "id": "35", "name": "Singaporean" },
    { "id": "147", "name": "Fijian" },
    { "id": "148", "name": "Tongan" },
    { "id": "150", "name": "Cook Islander" },
    { "id": "156", "name": "Northern European" },
    { "id": "157", "name": "Latin European" },
    { "id": "158", "name": "Central American" },
    { "id": "159", "name": "South American Indian" },
    { "id": "160", "name": "Hawaiian" },
    { "id": "161", "name": "East African" },
    { "id": "162", "name": "West African" },
    { "id": "163", "name": "Northern African" },
    { "id": "164", "name": "Eskimo" },
    { "id": "165", "name": "Arabic" },
    { "id": "166", "name": "Southern African" }
]
```

I have mapped out this data as MUI chips

```
{chipData.map((c) => (
    <Chip label={c.name} key={c.id} onClick={handleClick} />
))}
```

What I need to do is make each Chip selectable and then get all the selected Chip transferred to match the Chips selected using a Autocomplete with a button click.

So basically, there will be 2 ways to select the Chips.

1. Using Autocomplete (Type and Select)
2. From a modal that shows all the chips and be able to select it like checkbox (Click and Select)

I have tried using `useState` but the problem is all the Chips are sharing one `useState` so whenever one is selected/unselected, all follows.

I am kind of stuck here but can't seem to find a similar solution on what I am trying to do.
Any insight/solution would really help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function Chip({name, onClick, variant, children}){
    return (
        <div className={variant} onClick={onClick}>{children}</div>
    )
}

const listOfChips = [
  { id: "4", name: "Caucasian" },
  { id: "5", name: "Asian" },
  { id: "6", name: "Middle Eastern" },
  { id: "7", name: "Eurasian" },
  { id: "8", name: "African" },
  { id: "10", name: "Caribbean" },
  { id: "11", name: "Scandinavian European" },
  { id: "12", name: "Afro American" },
  { id: "13", name: "Latin American" },
  { id: "14", name: "European" },
  { id: "15", name: "Slavic European" },
  { id: "16", name: "American Indian" },
  { id: "17", name: "Inuit" },
  { id: "21", name: "Aboriginal/Torres Strait" },
  { id: "22", name: "Maori" },
  { id: "23", name: "Pacific Islander" },
  { id: "24", name: "Indian" },
  { id: "26", name: "Cambodian" },
  { id: "27", name: "Korean" },
  { id: "28", name: "Vietnamese" },
  { id: "29", name: "Thai" },
  { id: "30", name: "Chinese" },
  { id: "31", name: "Malaysian" },
  { id: "32", name: "Filipino" },
  { id: "33", name: "Japanese" },
  { id: "34", name: "Indonesian" },
  { id: "35", name: "Singaporean" },
  { id: "147", name: "Fijian" },
  { id: "148", name: "Tongan" },
  { id: "150", name: "Cook Islander" },
  { id: "156", name: "Northern European" },
  { id: "157", name: "Latin European" },
  { id: "158", name: "Central American" },
  { id: "159", name: "South American Indian" },
  { id: "160", name: "Hawaiian" },
  { id: "161", name: "East African" },
  { id: "162", name: "West African" },
  { id: "163", name: "Northern African" },
  { id: "164", name: "Eskimo" },
  { id: "165", name: "Arabic" },
  { id: "166", name: "Southern African" },
];

function App() {
  const [allChips, setAllChips] = React.useState(listOfChips);
  const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState(new Set());

  function handleSelectionChanged(id) {
    // treat state as immutable
    // React only does a shallow comparison so we need a new Set
    const newSet = new Set(selected);
    if (newSet.has(id)) newSet.delete(id);
    else newSet.add(id);
    setSelected(newSet);
  }

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {allChips.map((c) => (
        <Chip
          key={c.id}
          onClick={() => handleSelectionChanged(c.id)}
          variant={selected.has(c.id) ? "filled" : "outlined"}
        >
          {c.name}
        </Chip>
      ))}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
div {
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.filled {
   background-color: black;
   color: white;
   border: 1px solid white;
}

.outlined {
   background-color: white;
   color: black;
   border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

One way (there are other ways) is to use a `Set` which holds all the IDs that are already selected and based on what if an ID is in the Set or not you could do some conditional rendering.

> I have created a component chip here to show that it works you can of course use the MUI Chip and use the `variant` prop, or something else of course.

Whenever a `Chip` is clicked you just check whether it is within the Set. If it is not, add it. If it is, remove it.

As far as your typing in an input field goes the approach is quite straighforward. You need an input field and `onChange` you need to search for the possible chips by `name` e.g. using `startsWith()` (or some more advanced auto-completion) and as soon as the user selects a specific chip you will have the `id` of that chip and can call `handleSelectionChanged(id)` with that ID. This would of course mean that if you type it twice it will be removed again, but you could certainly change the logic for this as well.

Comment: I am getting an error. It says "No overload matches this call".

Both says `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'null | undefined'`

Comment: `c` seems to be empty....

Comment: nevermind, i just needed to add a label

Comment: Oh yeah, had to write JavaScript to make it executable here. So yes there are some small adjustments to do for this to work for Typescript.